# Как правильно записывать и читать данные с mongodb одновременно?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Я новичок в mongodb. Я так понимаю, из-за `конкуренции` я не могу читать и записывать данные в коллекцию одновременно. Потому что если я записываю данные в одной функции и их читаю в другой функции, то он постоянно читает значения, которые были записаны в первый раз и больше вообще не может обновить эти данные. Однако если я комментирую чтение данных, то он записывает всё так, как и должно. Как я могу от этого избавиться? Я пишу бота телеграмм на JS с использованием TeleBot и развёртываю его в Vercel.

Comment: Чтение и запись - асинхронные действия... Если хочешь читать что-то после записи - нужно это делать не "на следующей строчке" программы. Нужно дожидаться окончания записи...